# Error Installing linphone from source

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I want to build a linphone from source code. I followed the guidelines on the (https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Linphone/Linphone%20and%20Raspberry%20Pi/)
but the linphone-sdk clone source code process is done separately because it always fails if done along with linphone-desktop.

When trying to build a linphone application, the following error occurs when building the libvpx library.

```
Unable to invoke compiler : /usr/bin/cc    -mx32 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
```

But when I check the cc using `which cc` command, it already available and show `/usr/bin/cc`.
Can anyone help solve the following problem?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but hope this will point in the semi-correct direction... The `makefile` could specify its own path for `cc`, which is usually applicable only inside the script (i.e. it doesn't modify your system environment variable, so `which cc` may not be the same). Another possible issue could be in the `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` key. I don't know what it does, please read the docs - is it setting the architecture to 64-bit? How about the `-mx32`? Is it setting the architecture to 32-bit Intel? Raspberry Pi is 32 bit Arm.

Comment: thank for your answer, I will try using hardcode to specify the cc path in the source code. I'm installing ubuntu 18.04 in my raspi.